# LINQ and string comparison

Tags: linq

I have a SQL table that has a column called 'Culture'. It includes values like 'en', 'en-GB', 'de-DE' etc. I'm using LINQ to query the SQL table. When I try to compare 'en-GB' to the value in the Culture field - 'en' like below -

```
bool recordExists = context.Table.Any(x => x.ItemID.Equals(item.ID.ToString()) 
                    && x.Culture.Equals(item.Language.Name));
```

The value of x.ItemID is 'en' and item.ID.ToString() is 'en-GB'. But on an equals() comparison is returning true. Is the hyphen in 'en-GB' causing an issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it really happens?

Comment: How do you know that x.ItemID has 'en' ?

Comment: I checked the values in the debugger.

Comment: Can you look at the generated SQL?

Comment: remove Equals Comparison check with normal string... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx